# Finding the maximum condition number of a matrix after erasure

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, gaussian, numerical-methods

I am dealing with the following question: Given a random Gaussian matrix of large size, say for example 1000 by 500. Then arbitrarily remove 500 rows and consider the condition number of the matrix left. What is the maximum possible condition number we can get with high probability?

Here Gaussian matrix means the matrix has i.i.d standard normal entries. I would like to write a MATLAB program to do some simulations. How can I write the program? Thanks for any help.

Comment: That condition number is going to vary widely depending on what contents that matrix will contain.  I can't see how you'd theoretically find this condition number if the matrix contents change. You said "Gaussian" matrix: I'm assuming a matrix generated by a Gaussian random distribution?  What would the mean and s.d. be?  "With high probability" in this case of randomness is to iterate many times by removing 500 rows from this matrix and finding the condition number.... then save the largest condition number.  Do you mean to say the maximum possible condition number **given an input matrix**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting problem. I don't know of any theoretical results, but it's easy to set up a Monte Carlo simulation and see.

Note that *arbitrarily* removing 500 rows is equivalent to always removing the *last* 500 rows for example, because the rows are i.i.d. and the condition number is invariant to changing the order of the rows.

```
M = 100; %// initial number of rows
N = 50; %// number of columns
R = 1e4; %// number of Monte Carlo realizations
cond1 = NaN(1,R); %// preallocate
cond2 = NaN(1,R); %// preallocate
for r = 1:R
    X = randn(M,N); %// matrix with i.i.d normalized Gaussian entries
    cond1(r) = cond(X);
    cond2(r) = cond(X(1:N,:));
end
loglog(cond1, cond2, '.', 'markersize', 1) %// scatter plot of results in logarithmic scale
xlabel('Condition number of original matrix')
ylabel('Condition number of reduced matrix')
```

This is the result for `M=100; N=50;`. Note that for `M=100; N=50;` it may take long to obtain a large number of realizations.

[image]

As expected, the condition number increases when you remove rows (although I didn't expect it to increase so much!).

From the obtained vectors `cond1` and `cond2` you can compute statistics, or percentiles. For example, the value that is exceeded with only 10% probability is, in each case,

```
>> quantile(cond1,.9)
ans =
   5.837510220358853
>> quantile(cond2,.9)
ans =
     9.422516183444204e+02
```

This means that in the original matrix, 90% of the times the condition number is less than `5.8375`; whereas in the reduced matrix, 90% of the times the condition number is less than `942.25`.

Comment: Nice simulation! If you introduce correlation across the rows (eg. by drawing each column from a correlated, multivariate normal distribution), you can make the effect even bigger!

I'm not sure what the context of his problem is, but depending on how his input matrix is generated, randomly remove 500 rows could have an even bigger impact on condition number.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I got some idea from this answer. Actually what I would like to consider is a more complicated problem: there are in total 1000 choose 500 ways to remove 500 rows, what I am interested is the maximum possible condition number that could be obtained among all these possibilities. So will the program be different with this setting?

Comment: Well, that's a different matter. For that you can build a loop and in each iteration use `Xreduced = X(randperm(1000,500),:` to build a matrix with a random set of 500 rows from the original one `X`